# How many tourists are allowed in Antarctica at one time?

Tags: antarctica, ecotourism

A user on [reddit claimed that](http://www.reddit.com/r/solotravel/comments/11q1gw/first_solo_tripecuador_peru_chile_and_antarctica/c6ouf0r) only 100 tourists are allowed on Antarctica at any one time.

Is there actually a limit or is he misinformed?  I know that there are limits in places like the Inca Trail, but this is the first I've heard of a total limit on Antarctic landings...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I could not find any reference that confirms these claims. Anyway I found out this [article in *The Guardian*](http://www.guardian.co.uk/world/2009/apr/19/antarctica-cruise-ship-visitors-ecosystem):

> Cruise ships carrying more than 500 passengers will be prohibited from landing anyone. Only 100 visitors are to be allowed on shore at any given time, in an attempt to prevent damage to the region's unique ecosystem.

So it seems that the limits are for the ships to not allow more than 100 passengers on land in Antarctica. According to the same article the visitors to Antarctica are around 45,000 annually. With simple calculations you will find out that if these visitors stayed one day only there could be more than 100 people at the same time.

Comment: 100 visitors... from one ship. Nothing to say you can't have 5 ships at 5 different beaches with 100 people each.

Comment: I doubt any of those cruise ship tourist spend the night on Antarctica.